# benchmark multiple URLs using ab

Tags: apache, web, benchmarking

I'm trying to use "ab" to load test a website.    I can't quite see how to hit more than one url using it,  round-robin style.    Is there a trick to doing this?

I saw some people starting ab with an &,  but this isn't quite what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ab can't do this,  but this github project can.    takes a file with a list of URLs.

https://github.com/philipgloyne/apachebench-for-multi-url

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative for performing benchmarks with several URLs is [siege](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege).

```
# install
sudo apt install siege

# show config
siege -C

# show help
siege --help
```

1. Create a file with a list of URls, e.g. in /var/tmp/urls.txt
2. Run siege

no concurrency, run 10 tests:

```
siege -b -c 1 -r once -i -f /var/tmp/urls_file.txt --no-parser --no-follow
```

To run siege with just one URL (like ab), you can omit the -f parameter and pass the URL as argument:

```
siege -b -c 1 -r 10 --no-parser --no-follow "https://example.org"
```

Example output:

```
{   "transactions":                   10,
    "availability":               100.00,
    "elapsed_time":                 3.96,
    "data_transferred":             0.43,
    "response_time":                0.40,
    "transaction_rate":             2.53,
    "throughput":                   0.11,
    "concurrency":                  1.00,
    "successful_transactions":             0,
    "failed_transactions":                 0,
    "longest_transaction":              0.43,
    "shortest_transaction":             0.00
}
```

Options:

- `-c`: CONCURRENT users, default is 10
- `-r`, --reps=NUM: REPS, number of times to run the test.
  If `--reps=once`, then each user will run through the urls.txt  file exactly one time.
- `-i`, `--internet` : INTERNET user simulation, hits URLs randomly.

Answer (score 3):

With Apache Benchmark (AB) it's not possible to hit multiple URL's from a single instance.

You have to use multiple test or alternative is using tool like JMeter to achieve your requirement.

Note: Apache Benchmark doesn't test things like image processing, ajax calls, etc. which you might be expecting in real world scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parallel` command to run multiple `ab` commands simultaneously. More details with [Simon Holywell](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2015/06/parallel-benchmark-many-urls-with-apachebench/)