# Benchmark a webserver with different requests

Tags: apache, webserver, benchmarking

I am now using Apache Benchmark

I have written simple test like, for example

```
    ab -n 5000 -c 20 http://www.google.com/?search=xxx
```

this allows benchmarking webserver always with same search query. Is that possible to benchmark a webserver with a list of different search?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112393/benchmark-multiple-urls-using-ab. While here, you want several different query parameters, but that can be generalize to several different URLs

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this with the default ab tool. There are several alternative tools out there which do allow you to specify a list of URLs to benchmark.

**ApacheBench**

https://code.google.com/p/apachebench-for-multi-url/

This is an extension of the ab tool and allows you to specify a list of files using the -L option. You will need to compile it yourself though.

**Siege**

Seige is another well known tool for benchmarking and superior to ab. You should be able to install it via your package manager (yum install siege). You can specify the URLs in  SIEGE_HOME/etc/urls.txt or alternatively create your own URL list file and specify the --file option with the path to your custom URL file.